# Save password toggle state when rotating phone

Tags: java, android

I'm totally new to android and I got my first task which is supposed to be simple, so the task is that I should add a password toggle to the password input field so that it can be shown/hidden when pressed and that was easy I only added this line in the TextInputLayout and it worked:

`app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"`

Now the thing is when I rotate the phone I lose the state of the toggle, so if I'm showing the password and I rotated the phone by default it hides the text, I was reading about `Bundle savedInstanceState` but I can't reference the default password toggle from inside the java class

Answer (score 1):

You should use `savedInstanceState` for the best practice. But you can also set `configChanges` to your activity. Your activity won't re-create again when rotate.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|navigation"
```

You can also handle screen rotate event in your activity.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        int orientation = newConfig.orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            // portrait
        } else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            // landscape
        }
    }
```

Comment: I took by your advice and I'm trying to use the savedInstanceState, I'm using now icons from material design that change based on a clickEvent and also I'm hiding/showing the password based on the event
Thanks a lot